# Electrostatics question about three identical styrofoam balls suspended from a fixed point, asking to solve for charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Three identical small Styrofoam balls ($m = 2.06\ \text{g}$) are suspended from a fixed point by three nonconducting threads, each with a length of $46.6\ \text{cm}$ and with negligible mass. At equilibrium the three balls form an equilateral triangle with sides of $29.3\ \text{cm}$. What is the common charge q carried by each ball?

Now, I thought that I'd need to use Coulomb's law on each ball and add the force that the two other balls exert on it, but that didn't work... I don't know how to use the length of the string, I only used the sides as $r$ in my initial attempt. Help please!

Comment: You want to calculate the force needed to deflect a ball from the vertical by a certain distance (not the length of the side of the triangle! Draw yourself a picture). Force is $mg\sin\theta$ - where $\theta$ is the angle of deflection. That's where the length of the strong comes in...

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: While Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).